# Is ED A0 80 ED B0 80 a valid UTF-8 byte sequence?

Tags: java, language-agnostic, unicode, utf-8

[java.nio.charset.Charset.forName("utf8").decode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#decode%28java.nio.ByteBuffer%29) decodes a byte sequence of

```
 ED A0 80 ED B0 80
```

into the Unicode codepoint:

```
 U+10000
```

[java.nio.charset.Charset.forName("utf8").decode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#decode%28java.nio.ByteBuffer%29) also decodes a byte sequence of

```
 F0 90 80 80
```

into the Unicode codepoint:

```
 U+10000
```

This is verified by the [code below](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8843742/632951/#snippet1).

Now this seems to be telling me that the UTF-8 encoding scheme will decode `ED A0 80 ED B0 80` and `F0 90 80 80` into the same unicode codepoint.

However, if I visit [https://www.google.com/search?query=**%ED%A0%80%ED%B0%80**](https://www.google.com/search?query=%ED%A0%80%ED%B0%80),

I can see that it is clearly different from the page [https://www.google.com/search?query=**%F0%90%80%80**](https://www.google.com/search?query=%F0%90%80%80)

Since the Google Search is using UTF-8 encoding scheme (correct me if I'm wrong) as well,

This suggests that the UTF-8 does not decode `ED A0 80 ED B0 80` and `F0 90 80 80` into the same unicode codepoint(s).

So basically I was wondering, by the *official* standard, should UTF-8 decode `ED A0 80 ED B0 80` byte sequence into the Unicode codepoint U+10000 ?

**Code**:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.nio.ByteBuffer bb = java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[] { (byte) 0xED, (byte) 0xA0, (byte) 0x80, (byte) 0xED, (byte) 0xB0, (byte) 0x80 });
        java.nio.CharBuffer cb = java.nio.charset.Charset.forName("utf8").decode(bb);
        for (int x = 0, xx = cb.limit(); x < xx; ++x) {
            System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(cb.get(x)));
        }
        System.out.println();
        bb = java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[] { (byte) 0xF0, (byte) 0x90, (byte) 0x80, (byte) 0x80 });
        cb = java.nio.charset.Charset.forName("utf8").decode(bb);
        for (int x = 0, xx = cb.limit(); x < xx; ++x) {
            System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(cb.get(x)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get two very different strings when I UTF-8 decode that in LINQPad (C#). The latter actually results in an "invalid surrogate pair" when character-wise access is attempted.

Comment: @pst Are you saying that the decoding algorithm which Java uses is flawed?

Comment: @Pacerier: well, the Java UTF-8 implementation is [known to be flawed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CESU-8).

Comment: @larsmans ok The article states "In normal usage, the Java programming language supports standard UTF-8 when reading and writing strings through InputStreamReader and OutputStreamWriter. However it uses Modified UTF-8 for object serialization, for the Java Native Interface, and for embedding constant strings in class files." Do you know what's the reason for this *anomaly* (read: unneeded complexity) ?

Comment: @Pacerier: backwards compatibility. Java was one of the first technologies to embrace Unicode, and it did so before the Unicode standard had "settled".

Comment: @larsmans Ic, though I've got to say that *backwards compatibility* is also the reason Java is so ugly and bloated at times.

Comment: Backwards compatibility is also the reason UTF-16 exists in the first place.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ED A0 80 ED B0 80` is the UTF-8 encoding of the UTF-16 surrogate pair `D800 DC00`.  This is **NOT** allowed in [UTF-8](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2279.txt):

> However, pairs of UCS-2 values between D800 and DFFF (surrogate pairs
>   in Unicode parlance)...need special treatment: **the UTF-16
>   transformation must be undone**, yielding a UCS-4 character that is then
>   transformed as above.

However, such an encoding *is* used in [CESU-8](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr26/) and Java's "Modified UTF-8".

> Since the Google Search is using UTF-8 encoding scheme (correct me if I'm wrong) as well,

It appears, based on the search box, that Google is using some kind of encoding auto-detection.  If you pass it `F0 90 80 80`, which is valid UTF-8, it interprets it as UTF-8 ().  If you pass it `ED A0 80 ED B0 80`, which is invalid UTF-8, it interprets it as [windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) (`í�€í°€`).

Comment: I had no idea it was modified in a way "not recommended ... for open information exchange" :(

Comment: @dan04 Ok to confirm what you have said, you are suggesting that `java.nio.charset.Charset.forName("utf8").decode` should throw an error (which it didn't) when we feed it with `ED A0 80 ED B0 80` ?

Answer (score 1):

Java's UTF8 is really a [CESU-8](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CESU-8) variant. The first case is using surrogate pairs encoded in UTF8 "style".

Answer (score 0):

```
F0 90 80 80
```

decodes as `U+10000`, or `LINEAR B SYLLABLE B008 A`.

```
ED A0 80 ED B0 80
```

decodes as `U+d800 U+dc00`.