# Java XSLT output incorrectly showing A0, B7 characters in browser

Tags: java, xml, xslt, encoding, utf-8

I have a Java/XML/XSL based web application that takes an XML document from another service and we then display the main text mode.

Both sites show the same block of text (which can include HTML formatting, English/French).  The main site displays fine, but my site is displaying certain characters incorrectly.   All content including the french characters display correctly except these few.

Inspecting the document I see A0, B7, not showing correctly.

Searching this site I found this question/response:

[Is ED A0 80 ED B0 80 a valid UTF-8 byte sequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843742/is-ed-a0-80-ed-b0-80-a-valid-utf-8-byte-sequence)

In the accepted answer it takes about illegal UTF-8 being interpreted as Windows-1252.   Those characters he shows are the ones I'm seeing.

As far as I know the document comes to my site UTF-8 (from a .NET based web app if that matters) and we store it as such, and display back as such.  It's stored as an XML document and transformed to show the output.

The block is displayed with disable-output-escaping (so that the HTML formatting shows) and that appears to be working correctly.

Ideally I would be able to display these characters as they were intended (A0 being a space) so that my output looks the same as a parent site.

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: Can you add a list of byte hex codes? Do supply a string longer than where the error occurs, so that we can better determine what the error may be.

Comment: `<p style="margin: 0cm 0cm 0pt 36pt;"><span><span style="font-family: symbol; font-size: 9pt;">׼span style="line-height: normal; font-variant: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 7pt; font-weight: normal;">     </span></span><span style="font-size: 9pt;">.</span></span></p>`
Pasting probably won't capture it - but you can see one span tag has a bad opening, B7 code.   The main hex codes I'm seeing are ED A0 80 ED B0 80

Comment: Pretty sure this is what's happening: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replacement_character#Replacement_character - my source may be Windows-1252 identifying as UTF-8.  I'm just not sure what to do about it.

Answer (score 1):

There's basically a misunderstanding between the XSLT processor, which is outputting the result using one encoding A, and the display software, which is rendering the document in the belief that its encoding is B. You haven't given enough information to determine what A and B are; and you haven't been specific about the "display software", which I suspect is the combination of a web server and a browser. Check that the encoding specified in the content (XML declaration or HTML charset declaration), the encoding specified in the HTTP header, and the actual encoding of the bytes are all consistent with each other.

Answer (score 0):

The character bytes you supplied (`ED A0 80` and `ED B0 80`) are unicode characters for so called surrogates, which always appear in pairs.
See [Wikipedia unicode surrogates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_of_Unicode_characters#Surrogates). For unicode surrogate character subset see [Unicode overview](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl).
Next step is figuring out how they got there :-)